# TypeError("'_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable")

Tags: python

The code should finds. But i get the error:

ValueError. can somebody please help me with a solution? thanks.

```
integers.close() # closes the file

# print results
print (smallest, biggest)
```

Comment: Your problem is that you have spaces in your number, and a trailing `\n` :) It's also a redicilously large number. So do `int(line.strip().replace(' ', ''))` and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the reading the file or each line of the file provides a String type line, your program doesn't handle the input in the proper way.
If you want you code to work you should do:

```
integers = open('/home/user/Documents/number.txt', 'r')
biggest = float('-inf')
smallest = float('inf')

for line in integers:
    for number in line.split(' '): # Splitting the line counting on spacing between numbers
        curr = int(number) # Casting each string to an integer type
        if biggest < curr:
            biggest = curr
        if smallest > curr:
            smallest = curr

integers.close()  # closes the file

# print results
print(smallest, biggest)
```

---

If you want to read/write files in Python I'd recommend using a file handler,you can read further [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

In the example here I've:

- opened the files and read all the lines to a list
- Using list comprehension I've build a list of the numbers
- Using Python build-in math function max and min I've printed them from the list.

The Code:

```
    with open('number.txt', 'r') as txtfile:
        numbers_list = txtfile.readlines()
    numbers = [int(num) for curr_line in numbers_list for num in curr_line.split(' ')]
    print(min(numbers), max(numbers))
```

Comment: Although the code shown may be "correct", the OP might be unfamiliar with the method/function you've added (e.g. `.split()` or `open`). However, without explanation, this only encourages a "give me teh codez" behaviour. As a suggestion on writing a better answer, please elaborate (or link the OP to appropriate/helpful documentation for further reading) on the changes you've made to the OP's code and in solving his issue. Thanks!

Comment: I was editing my answer and accidentally pressed post, though your comment is correct it's just not the case here :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, is caused by wrong processing of content you readed from file.
To discard newline character (`\n`) from end of line you can use `.rstrip('\n')` method, example:

```
x = '1 2 3\n'
y = x.rstrip('\n')
print(y)
```

will print:
`1 2 3` (without newline)

Alternatively you could use `.splitlines()` method, as follows:

```
file = open('numbers.txt','r')
data = file.read().splitlines()
file.close()
```

In this case `data` would be `list` of `str`s, each representing one line of file. You would need to use `.split(' ')` method to get particular numbers and `int` to convert from `str` to `int`, for example:

```
a = '1 2 3'
b = [int(i) for i in a.split(' ')]
print(b) #prints [1, 2, 3]
```

After getting correct `list` of `int`s, you might implement own *min* or *max* finding.